# Solve: $4(9^x)+3(4^x)=13(6^x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, exponential-function, problem-solving

I'm new to this site so bear with me if I make some mistakes. Here is the question:

Solve: $4(9^x)+3(4^x)=13(6^x)$

I have absolutely no clue how to attack this problem. I have tried a bit of logs but I come to a dead end. What could I do?

Comment: Hi, for questions like this, we usually ask you to provide some information on what you have tried and why it didn't work for you, so that we can give you actual advice instead of solving the problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @JohannesKloos - for this one I had little idea, probably because I'm also very tired! But I will keep your advice in mind in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing both sides by $4^{x}$:

$4(\frac{9}{4})^{x} + 3 = 13(\frac{3}{2})^{x}$

$4(\frac{3}{2})^{2x} - 13(\frac{3}{2})^{x} + 3 = 0$

Note that this is a quadratic in $(\frac{3}{2})^{x}$, which can be factored as:

$(4(\frac{3}{2})^{x}-1)((\frac{3}{2})^{x}-3) = 0$

Thus, we either have $(\frac{3}{2})^{x} = \frac{1}{4}$ or $(\frac{3}{2})^{x}=3$, which gives a solution set of $\boxed{x = -\log_{\frac{3}{2}}(4), \log_{\frac{3}{2}}(3).}$

If you want, you can use change-of-base and log rules to get everything in normal $\log$s.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Rewrite $4(9^x) + 3(4^x) = 13(6^x)$ as $4(3^x)^2 + 3(2^x)^2 = 13 (2^x)(3^x)$.